# MongoDB replica set initiate

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I am quite new to MongoDB and have following question for replica set initiation.

When I tried to initiate a replica set from standalone mongod, I tried:

```
> use admin
> config = {id: "rs_name", members: [{id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017"}]}
> db.runCommand('replSetInitiate', config)

"info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
"ok": 1
...
```

Here is the first curiosity: **Why did it show "no configuration" as I already assigned "config" as replica set configuration?**

Though replica set was founded, when I tired:

```
> use local
> db.system.replset.find().pretty()

...
"members": [
   {
      "host": "here is hostname insted of host IP"
   }
...
```

Here is the second ponit I didn't get: **Why did the replica information show host name instead of host IP as value of property "host"?**

But When I tried a different way:

```
> use admin
> config = {id: "rs_name", members: [{id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017"}]}
> rs.initiate(config)
```

It went well and did not give any message like "no configuration specified". Replica information also showed host IP instead of host name.

Here is the last one: **What is the difference between mechanism of `replSetInitiate` and `rs.initiate` when we try to initiate a replica set?**

Comment: To see the underlying code, execute `rs.intiate` (just like that with no parenthesis) from the mongo shell.

Answer (score 2):

> config = {id: "rs_name", members: [{id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017"}]}

1. replace id to _id

> db.runCommand('replSetInitiate', config)

2. use `db.runCommand({replSetInitiate : config})` instead

> Here is the second ponit I didn't get: Why did the replica information show host name instead of host IP as value of property "host"?

3. As mongodb docs described `When possible, use a logical DNS hostname instead of an ip address, particularly when configuring replica set members or sharded cluster members.` .
   In the first step, you got `no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set`, the default configuration may use hostname instead of ip address.

FROM: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetInitiate/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below and use **_id** which is highlighted below

> use admin config = {
> **_id** : "rs_name",
> members : [
> {**_id** : 0, host : "IP:27017"}
> ] }
>
> rs.initiate(config)